# Unexpected reserved word 'yield' in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, yield

In my `react` project, including `react-redux`, I'm trying to use `yield` in an catch error function for an `axios` request like this:

```
const result = yield axios.put(REQUEST_API, data, config)
  .catch(error => {
    yield put({ type: SET_MESSAGE, message: `ERROR_HAPPENED: ${error.response.data.status}` });
  });
```

But as the catch error function is not a generator, I'm getting this error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'yield'

So I tried to change the error function to a generator:

```
const result = yield axios.put(REQUEST_API, data, config)
  .catch(function* (error) {
    yield put({ type: SET_MESSAGE, message: `ERROR_HAPPENED: ${error.response.data.status});
  });
```

But now I'm getting this warning from `eslint`:

> Unexpected unnamed generator function.

I'm not sure what's wrong with this approach, but this way `axios` never catches the error!

So is there any better practice to dispatch an action with `yield put` if an error happened in `axios` request?

Answer (score 2):

`yield` can be used directly inside the context of `Generators`, and here you are using it inside a wrapped promise catch which comes with its own lexical context.

The right way to do it is:

```
try {
   const result = yield axios.put(REQUEST_API, data, config);
   ... your more code...
} catch (err) {
   yield put({ type: SET_MESSAGE, message: `ERROR_HAPPENED`); 
}
```

The fact that if a promise is made to await in a try block then the promise's catch would automatically fall in the catch of the try block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you also know a way not to display `axios` error in console? Cause even with `try catch` block, the error is shown in the console

Comment: Can you attach the stack-trace of the error you are talking please ?